# Custom ListView Adapter with multiple TextView gets duplicated every row

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, android-listview

I am using a Custom ListView to show 3 different strings on 3 TextViews every row.
It should go like:

```
Customer 1
Type 1
Date 1
-------
Customer 2
Type 2
Date 2
-------
Customer 3
...
```

The problem is it shows every single row with the information from the last customer. I have checked the information passed to the CustomAdapter and is correct plus I tried different methods to implement this but none worked and as I'm not familiar with Android Studio I can't really find what's wrong exactly.

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    ArrayList<InfoModel> listDisplay = new ArrayList<InfoModel>();
    InfoModel data = new InfoModel();
    ListView listView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.customerslist);

        // This here just takes the data from a local database and puts it into the ArrayList. I've checked it and the data passed to the adapter is correct
        DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
        List<HolidaysModel> list = dataBaseHelper.getAllTable("HOLIDAYS_TABLE");
        List<CustomerModel> list2 = dataBaseHelper.getAllTable("CUSTOMER_TABLE");

        for (HolidaysModel holidays: list) {
            data.setType(holidays.getType());
            data.setDates(new StringBuilder().append(holidays.getDateStart()).append(" - ").append(holidays.getDateFinish()).toString());
            for (CustomerModel customer: listCustomer) {
                if(customer.get_id() == (Integer) holidays.getId()) {
                    data.setName(new StringBuilder().append(customer.getName()).append(" ").append(customer.getSurname()).toString());
                    listDisplay.add(data);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        CustomAdapter arrayAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, listDisplay);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/customerslist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**CustomAdapter.class**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final Context context;
    private ArrayList<InfoModel> items = new ArrayList<InfoModel>();

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<InfoModel> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public InfoVacacionesModel getItem(int i) {
        return items.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        TextView tv_name;
        TextView tv_type;
        TextView tv_dates;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View oneLine, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(oneLine == null) {
            oneLine = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.tv_name = (TextView) oneLine.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            holder.tv_type = (TextView) oneLine.findViewById(R.id.tv_type);
            holder.tv_dates = (TextView) oneLine.findViewById(R.id.tv_dates);

            oneLine.setTag(holder);
        }

        else 
            holder =  (ViewHolder) oneLine.getTag();        

        holder.tv_name.setText(items.get(position).getName());
        holder.tv_type.setText(items.get(position).getType());
        holder.tv_dates.setText(items.get(position).getDates());

        return oneLine;
    }
}
```

**custom_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/tv_type"
        android:textSize="15sp">
    </TextView>


    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/tv_dates"
        android:textSize="15sp">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In MainActivity declare InfoModel objects within the for:

```
   for (HolidaysModel holidays: list) {
        InfoModel data = new InfoModel();
        data.setType(holidays.getType());
        data.setDates(new StringBuilder().append(holidays.getDateStart()).append(" - ").append(holidays.getDateFinish()).toString());
        for (CustomerModel customer: listCustomer) {
            if(customer.get_id() == (Integer) holidays.getId()) {
                data.setName(new StringBuilder().append(customer.getName()).append(" ").append(customer.getSurname()).toString());
                listDisplay.add(data);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```